# How to get an image in P mode with my own palette

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, palette

I get some images in at most 30 colors, and I write a palette like this

```
palette = [0,0,0,70,130,180,70,70,70,...]
```

and then I want to read these images with this palette

```
img= Image.open(dir).convert('P', palette=palette, colors=30)
```

but when I check these palettes

```
print(img.getpalette())
```

I get some different palettes in different images. Then what should I do?

Comment: Can you show an example of say two small images that we can use to reproduce this issue?